# Rendering issue with glsurfaceview in GpuImage

Tags: java, android, gpuimage, glsurfaceview, imagefilter

Original image: [before processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Mm2.jpg)

Processed image on glsurfaceview: [after processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Ho7.jpg)

**Java code:**

```
mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
mGPUImage.setGLSurfaceView((GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.editPicture));
mGPUImage.setImage(uri);
```

**XML:**

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/editPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use

```
gpuImage.setImage(URI)
```

use

```
gpuImage.setImage(Bitmap)
```